# MYSQL QUERY with Self declared sequence column

Tags: mysql

I have table called `size`

with columns of `id`, `size`, `deleted`, `created_at`, `updated_at`

Currently I have this query

`SELECT * FROM size WHERE deleted = 0 ORDER BY size ASC`

It will give me something like this

```
id | size | deleted | created_at | updated_at
2  | 83   | 0       | 2014-04-15 | 2014-04-15
3  | 90   | 0       | 2014-04-15 | 2014-04-15
1  | 92   | 0       | 2014-04-15 | 2014-04-15
4  | 94   | 0       | 2014-04-15 | 2014-04-15
```

Now I want to add self declared column like `AS sequence` where it will give me the sequence number of these rows

My expected output would be something like this

`id | size | deleted | created_at | updated_at | sequence`

`2  | 83   | 0       | 2014-04-15 | 2014-04-15 | 1`

`3  | 90   | 0       | 2014-04-15 | 2014-04-15 | 2`

`1  | 92   | 0       | 2014-04-15 | 2014-04-15 | 3`

`4  | 94   | 0       | 2014-04-15 | 2014-04-15 | 4`

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: What defines the values in `sequence`? `size`?

Comment: @Nick - it's the number of row based on the arrangement of data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below query to print the sequence column,

SET @row_number = 0;
SELECT
(@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS sequence,
id,
size,
deleted,
created_at
updated_at
FROM
size
Where deleted = 0
ORDER BY size ASC

Comment: Just to observe that this is a rather old fashioned (and, I think, now deprecated) solution.